# grep for pattern including carriage return on a Mac

Tags: macos, grep, awk

I want to search files for colon followed by carriage return followed by dash.  I am using macOS (so it's BSD `grep`).

I would have thought

`grep -l ":\n-" filename-pattern`

would work, but it doesn't! And using

`grep -l ":\n-" filename-pattern`

doesn't work either.

Here's the octal dump of the line in question:

```
0000020    U   R       D   A   T   A   B   A   S   E   :  \n   -       T
```

Other posters have noted that since `grep` is line oriented, I will need to use `awk`, but I can't seem to get the pattern right - I am using

`awk '/:\n- /' filename`

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can explain the problem: `\n` doesn't represent a carriage return, that's a newline (aka linefeed) character. Which means the pattern actually spans two lines. Which doesn't really match what `grep` normally does, which is to look for matching lines (not groups of lines) in files.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gordon said grep won't be able to match multiline statements, but `awk` will be able to. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350856/can-awk-patterns-match-multiple-lines) is another question that will hopefully help you build the proper statement that you are looking for. Good luck!